# webpack production build bundle.js file size is 10mb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, production

I'm working on this react app and when I build the projects the `bundle.js` file is 10mb so after the deployment it takes time to load the content.

Here's the code: https://github.com/sef-global/scholarx-frontend

Here's my webpack config file:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const path = require('path');
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const webpack = require('webpack');
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ['@babel/env'] },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              lessOptions: { javascriptEnabled: true },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [{ loader: 'file-loader' }],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: true,
    hotOnly: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html',
      favicon: 'public/favicon.png',
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Your mode here is set as development, i don't see a command in packages.json where you would override this to production

Comment: can that be the issue?

Comment: Absolutely, let me post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume for production build you using your "build" command from `packages.json` which states:

```
"build": "webpack",
```

That will trigger `webpack` "building" of course, but in your webpack config the `mode` is set to `development` - so it will build in development mode.

What you want to do is this:

```
"build": "webpack --mode production",
```

`--mode` argument will override what you have in webpack.config.